# highcharts splines chart - large data should plot specific data only

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I created a splines highcharts with just 12 months of data (refer: Demo Example1) and able to plot it perfectly, since when there are large - 36 or 60 months of data (refer: Demo Example2) I need to plot quarterly data like (Mar-2020, Jun-2020, Sep-2020, Dec-2020 and so on...) How can I achieve it?

Demo Example 1: https://jsfiddle.net/hdaqg45f/1/

Demo Code 1:

```
var plotBands = [
            {
                color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
                from: 0,
                to: 30.99,
                zIndex: 3
            },
            {
                color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
                from: 31,
                to: 44.99,
                zIndex: 3
            },
            {
                color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
                from: 45,
                to: 54.99,
                zIndex: 3
            },
            {
                color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
                from: 55,
                to: 68.99,
                zIndex: 3
            },
            {
                color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
                from: 69,
                to: 87.99,
                zIndex: 3
            },
            {
                color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
                from: 88,
                to: 100,
                zIndex: 3
            }
        ];
    
    var dates = ['Mar-2020','Apr-2020','May-2020','Jun-2020','Jul-2020','Aug-2020','Sep-2020','Oct-2020','Nov-2020','Dec-2020','Jan-2021','Feb-2021'];
    
    var chartdata = [
        {
        color: "rgb(0,187,221)",
        data: [50,15,52,54,54,56,51,85,96,53,55,57],
        date: dates,
        name: 'RiskGauge Score',
        type: 'spline'
      },
      {
        color: "rgb(154,2,42)",
        data: [12,14,18,16,52,54,53,23,27,29,42,16],
        date: dates,
        name: 'United States of America Median',
        type: 'spline'
      }
    ]
    
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
          marginTop: 10,
          height: 250
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
          align: "center",
          layout: "horizontal",
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          alignColumns: false,
          itemDistance: 4,
          symbolHeight: 18,
          symbolWidth: 18,
          itemStyle: {
            fontSize: "11px !important"
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: chartdata[0].date,
          labels: {
            style: {
              fontSize: "11px !important",
              color: "#000"
            }
          },
          gridLineColor: "transparent",
          gridLineWidth: 0,
          lineWidth: 0,
          minorGridLineWidth: 0,
          lineColor: "transparent",
          minorTickLength: 0,
          tickLength: 0,
          style: {
            fontSize: "15px !important",
            color: "#000"
          }
        },
        yAxis: [
          {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            width: 20,
            tickInterval: 20,
            plotBands: plotBands,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            style: {
              fontSize: "10px",
              color: "red"
            },
            title: {
              text: ""
            },
            labels: {
              style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'black',   
                },
                formatter: function () {
                  return this.value;
                }
            },
          },
          {
            linkedTo: 0,
            gridLineColor:'white',
            lineColor: "transparent",
            title: {
              text: ""
            },
            labels: {
              enabled:false,
            },     
          },
        ],
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            states: {
              hover: {
                enabled: true
              },
              inactive: {
                opacity: 1
              }
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
            threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
            marker: {
              enabled: true
            },
            minPointLength: 10
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          useHTML: false,
          shared: false,
          followPointer: false
        },
        series: chartdata
      });
```

Demo Example 2: https://jsfiddle.net/hdaqg45f/s

Demo Code 2:

```
var plotBands = [
        {
            color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
            from: 0,
            to: 30.99,
            zIndex: 3
        },
        {
            color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
            from: 31,
            to: 44.99,
            zIndex: 3
        },
        {
            color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
            from: 45,
            to: 54.99,
            zIndex: 3
        },
        {
            color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
            from: 55,
            to: 68.99,
            zIndex: 3
        },
        {
            color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
            from: 69,
            to: 87.99,
            zIndex: 3
        },
        {
            color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
            from: 88,
            to: 100,
            zIndex: 3
        }
    ];

var dates = ['Mar-2020','Apr-2020','May-2020','Jun-2020','Jul-2020','Aug-2020','Sep-2020','Oct-2020','Nov-2020','Dec-2020','Jan-2021','Feb-2021','Mar-2021','Apr-2021','May-2021','Jun-2021','Jul-2021','Aug-2021','Sep-2021','Oct-2021','Nov-2021','Dec-2021','Jan-2022','Feb-2022','Mar-2022','Apr-2022','May-2022','Jun-2022','Jul-2022','Aug-2022','Sep-2022','Oct-2022','Nov-2022','Dec-2022','Jan-2023','Feb-2023'];

var chartdata = [
    {
    color: "rgb(0,187,221)",
    data: [50,15,52,54,54,56,51,85,96,53,55,57,50,15,52,54,54,56,51,85,96,53,55,57,50,15,52,54,54,56,51,85,96,53,55,57],
    date: dates,
    name: 'RiskGauge Score',
    type: 'spline'
  },
  {
    color: "rgb(154,2,42)",
    data: [12,14,18,16,52,54,53,23,27,29,42,16,12,14,18,16,52,54,53,23,27,29,42,16,12,14,18,16,52,54,53,23,27,29,42,16],
    date: dates,
    name: 'United States of America Median',
    type: 'spline'
  }
]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      marginTop: 10,
      height: 250
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      align: "center",
      layout: "horizontal",
      verticalAlign: "bottom",
      alignColumns: false,
      itemDistance: 4,
      symbolHeight: 18,
      symbolWidth: 18,
      itemStyle: {
        fontSize: "11px !important"
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: chartdata[0].date,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: "11px !important",
          color: "#000"
        }
      },
      gridLineColor: "transparent",
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      lineColor: "transparent",
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      style: {
        fontSize: "15px !important",
        color: "#000"
      }
    },
    yAxis: [
      {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        width: 20,
        tickInterval: 20,
        plotBands: plotBands,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: "10px",
          color: "red"
        },
        title: {
          text: ""
        },
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'black',   
            },
            formatter: function () {
              return this.value;
            }
        },
      },
      {
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineColor:'white',
        lineColor: "transparent",
        title: {
          text: ""
        },
        labels: {
          enabled:false,
        },     
      },
    ],
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true
          },
          inactive: {
            opacity: 1
          }
        },
        enableMouseTracking: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
        threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        },
        minPointLength: 10
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: false,
      shared: false,
      followPointer: false
    },
    series: chartdata
  });
```

Comment: @ppotaczek can you please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data to the required period - just skip every third value or sum the next three values. Example of implementation:

```
function convertDataToQuarterly(dataSet) {
    var quarterlyData = [];
    var isCategoriesData = isNaN(dataSet[0]);

    dataSet.forEach(function(dataEl, index) {
        if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
            quarterlyData.push(dataEl);

            if (!isCategoriesData) {
                quarterlyData[quarterlyData.length - 1] += dataSet[index - 1] + dataSet[index - 2];
            }
        }
    });

    return quarterlyData;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wav86bm5/

Comment: can you help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374543/highcharts-with-yaxis-max-property-doesnt-hide-plotbands-and-lables also?