# Highcharts with yaxis max property doesn't hide plotbands and lables

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created a two jsfiddle for demoing my issue. 1st jsfiddle is what I need and 2nd jsfiddle where I am facing an issue.

This jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/n5ua6krj/1/) is without max of yxis[0] and then clicks on both legends it hides plotbands, yaxis labels and gridlines. This works fine.

This jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/n5ua6krj/) is with max of yxis[0] as 100 and then clicks on both legends it doesn't hides plotbands, yaxis labels and gridlines. This is issue in my case. I want the same behavior as the above.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            height: 222,
            plotBorderColor: '#BFBFBF',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            spacingTop: 2.5,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 1,
            spacingBottom: 0,
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            itemStyle: {
                color: "#000",
                fontSize: "11px !important",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                textOverflow: null
            },
            symbolWidth: 20,
            x: 17,
            itemMarginBottom: 4,
            margin: 6
        },
        xAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.07,
            maxPadding: 0.02,
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                week: '%b<br/>%Y',
                month: '%b<br/>%Y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: "10px !important",
                    color: "#000"
                },
                x: 15
            },
            gridLineColor: "transparent",
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: "transparent",
            tickLength: 0,
            style: {
                fontSize: "10px !important",
                color: "#000"
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                min: 0,
                //max: 100, ----------> uncomment it and clicks on both the legends to see the issue
                width: 20,
                tickInterval: 20,
                plotBands: [
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
                        from: 0,
                        to: 30.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
                        from: 31,
                        to: 44.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
                        from: 45,
                        to: 54.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
                        from: 55,
                        to: 68.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
                        from: 69,
                        to: 87.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
                        from: 88,
                        to: 100,
                        zIndex: 3
                    }
                ],
                gridLineWidth: 0.5,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    x: -7,
                    y: 5,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                linkedTo: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                    animation: false,
                    turboThreshold: 0,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    radius: 2
                },
                minPointLength: 10,
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: false,
            shared: false,
            followPointer: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.y;
            }
        },
        series: [
        {
                    "color": "rgb(0,187,221)",
                    "data": [
                    { 'x': 1594578600000, 'y':73}, { 'x': 1594665000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1594751400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1594837800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1594924200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595183400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595269800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595356200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595442600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595529000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595788200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595874600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595961000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596047400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596133800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596393000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596479400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596565800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596652200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596738600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596997800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597084200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597170600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597257000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597343400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597602600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597689000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597775400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597861800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597948200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598207400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598293800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598380200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598466600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598553000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598812200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598898600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598985000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599071400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599157800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599417000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599503400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599589800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599676200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599762600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600021800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600108200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600194600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600281000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600367400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600626600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600713000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600799400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600885800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1600972200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1601231400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601317800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601404200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601490600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601577000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601836200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601922600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602009000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602095400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602181800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602441000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602527400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602613800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602700200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602786600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603045800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603132200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603218600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603305000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603391400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603650600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603737000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603823400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603909800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603996200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1604255400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1604341800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1604428200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1604514600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1604601000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1604860200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1604946600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605033000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605119400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605205800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605465000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605551400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605637800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605724200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605810600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606069800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606156200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606242600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606329000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606415400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606674600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606761000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606847400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606933800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607020200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607279400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607365800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607452200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607538600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607625000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607884200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607970600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608057000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608143400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608229800000, 'y':69}, { 'x': 1608489000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608575400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608661800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608748200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608834600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609093800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1609180200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1609266600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1609353000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609439400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609698600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609785000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609871400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609957800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610044200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610303400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610389800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610476200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610562600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610649000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610908200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610994600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611081000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611167400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611253800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611513000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1611599400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1611685800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611772200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611858600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1612117800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1612204200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612290600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1612377000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612463400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612722600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612809000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612895400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612981800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613068200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613327400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613413800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613500200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613586600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613673000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1613932200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614018600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614105000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614191400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1614277800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1614537000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614623400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614709800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614796200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614882600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615141800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615228200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615314600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615401000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615487400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615746600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615833000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615919400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616005800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616092200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616351400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616437800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616524200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616610600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616697000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616956200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617042600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617129000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617215400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617301800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617561000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617647400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617733800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617820200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617906600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618165800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618252200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618338600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618425000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618511400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618770600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618857000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618943400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619029800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619116200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619375400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619461800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619548200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619634600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619721000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619980200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620066600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620153000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620239400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620325800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620585000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620671400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620757800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620844200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620930600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621189800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621276200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621362600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621449000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621535400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621794600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621881000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621967400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622053800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622140200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622399400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622485800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622572200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622658600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622745000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623004200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623090600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623177000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623263400000, 'y':72}
                 ],
                    "name": 'ABC',
                    "type": 'spline',
                    "category": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgb(154,2,42)",
                    "data": [
                    { 'x': 1594578600000, 'y':73}, { 'x': 1594665000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1594751400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1594837800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1594924200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595183400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595269800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595356200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595442600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595529000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595788200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595874600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1595961000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596047400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596133800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596393000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596479400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596565800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596652200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596738600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1596997800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597084200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597170600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597257000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597343400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597602600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597689000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597775400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597861800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1597948200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598207400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598293800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598380200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598466600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598553000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598812200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598898600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1598985000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599071400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599157800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599417000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599503400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599589800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599676200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1599762600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600021800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600108200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600194600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600281000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600367400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600626600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600713000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600799400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1600885800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1600972200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1601231400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601317800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601404200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601490600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601577000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601836200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1601922600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602009000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602095400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602181800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602441000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602527400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602613800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602700200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1602786600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603045800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603132200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603218600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603305000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603391400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603650600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603737000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603823400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1603909800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1603996200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1604255400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1604341800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1604428200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1604514600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1604601000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1604860200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1604946600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605033000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605119400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605205800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605465000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605551400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605637800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605724200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1605810600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606069800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606156200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606242600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606329000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606415400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606674600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606761000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606847400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1606933800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607020200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607279400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607365800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607452200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607538600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607625000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607884200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1607970600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608057000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608143400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608229800000, 'y':69}, { 'x': 1608489000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608575400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608661800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608748200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1608834600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609093800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1609180200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1609266600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1609353000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609439400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609698600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609785000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609871400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1609957800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610044200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610303400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610389800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610476200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610562600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610649000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610908200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1610994600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611081000000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611167400000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611253800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611513000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1611599400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1611685800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611772200000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1611858600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1612117800000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1612204200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612290600000, 'y':70}, { 'x': 1612377000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612463400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612722600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612809000000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612895400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1612981800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613068200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613327400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613413800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613500200000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613586600000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1613673000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1613932200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614018600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614105000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614191400000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1614277800000, 'y':71}, { 'x': 1614537000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614623400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614709800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614796200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1614882600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615141800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615228200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615314600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615401000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615487400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615746600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615833000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1615919400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616005800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616092200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616351400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616437800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616524200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616610600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616697000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1616956200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617042600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617129000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617215400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617301800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617561000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617647400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617733800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617820200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1617906600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618165800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618252200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618338600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618425000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618511400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618770600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618857000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1618943400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619029800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619116200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619375400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619461800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619548200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619634600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619721000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1619980200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620066600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620153000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620239400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620325800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620585000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620671400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620757800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620844200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1620930600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621189800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621276200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621362600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621449000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621535400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621794600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621881000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1621967400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622053800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622140200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622399400000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622485800000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622572200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622658600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1622745000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623004200000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623090600000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623177000000, 'y':72}, { 'x': 1623263400000, 'y':72}
                    ],
                    "name": 'XYZ',
                    "type": 'spline',
                    "category": "XYZ"
                }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `softMax` instead of `max` property:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        softMax: 100,
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgvn0ux8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.softMax

Comment: It works but facing issue if any of my series data is 96 or more than of it. In that case yaxis shows labels up to 120, previously when were using only max that time it shows lables up to 100 only. can you also look into that?

Comment: Set `maxPadding` for y-axis to 0. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xm756rct/